# Issue: In case of multiLineSeries Graph if one of the series has no Data, the entire graph does not get plotted

Tags: typescript, highcharts

Please tell me if this is an issue or not. In a multiLine Series graph i.e a Multigraph if one of the series is empty, then the entire graph does not plot. Please see [enter link description here](https://jsfiddle.net/j5m4uf86/5/). I have an issue related to this, In my case I am plotting the graph which has data some how as I was storing it in my cache. But then the Measure operation does not work on them as there are other series which has no data in it. I hope I was able to explain, let me know in comments if it is still not clear.

```
data.push([]); //line 13 of the jsfiddle link
```

Answer (score 0):

You have Highcharts warining #12 in console:

> Highcharts expects point configuration to be numbers or arrays in
> turbo mode

However even if you disable turbo mode, you will have a warning about unsorted data, example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/89bf513d/

You should filter out elements with no data.

```
let data = (function() {
    ...

    return data.filter(dataEl => !isNaN(dataEl[0]));
}())
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/omzs8hrf/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column.turboThreshold